# How to post a picture in reply to a comment

Tags: support, questions, comments

Someone asked me to send them a picture of my spreadsheet in order to answer a question I submitted.  Can you please let me know if it is possible to post a PDF in reply to a comment, or if I can direct message an image to another user?

Comment: `[my amazing picture](http://www.example.com/picture.jpg)` -> [my amazing picture](http://www.example.com/picture.jpg)

Comment: Since spreadsheet data is just text, you should actually be posting the text itself rather than a screenshot of text. You can use code formatting so you can space the columns appropriately.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should respond to any requests for clarification by **clicking the 'edit' button** under your post rather than trying to add extra information in the comments. You'll then be able to [insert an image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75491/336144) using the regular editor, which allows you to drag and drop an image, or select from your file system. PDF documents are not supported, though — only static images (e.g. PNG, JPEG, and so on).

After you've finished editing, you can then reply to that user to let them know you've updated your post with the information they wanted.

Generally, it's best to edit to clarify your post rather than adding additional information in the comments. You don't need to add a big **EDIT** comment like in some forums since we have a [public edit history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38647/336144); just add the necessary details as if you'd posted the image with the rest of the post.